# chrome crash while setting popupWindow.innerHTML = largeString

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have to get log every minutes

```
var log = '';
setInterval(function(){
log += document.getElementById('div').innerHTML; //full of html tag
},60000);
```

and after couple hours

```
log.length // > 300000
```

and now show it in new window

```
var logWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=600");
logWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = log;
```

after this process my chrome got crashed and all freeze. any proper way to do this? I test by different pc and the results are same.

Comment: Looks like the previous contents is stuck in the heap: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround consider creating many elements:

```
var log = [];
setInterval(function() {
  log.push(document.getElementById('div').innerHTML);
}, 60000);
```

---

```
log.forEach(function(html) {
    logWindow.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>' + html + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an array of elements rather than a string to store your log. This way you can use `appendChild` to gradually add elements (using a loop) to `logWindow` and possibly avoid a crash.

Log code:

```
var log = [];
setInterval(function() {
    log.push(document.getElementById('div'))
}, 60000);
```

Pop up code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
    logWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(log[i])
}
```

Comment: [importNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) is required to add an element from a different document.